# Android Logcat not displaying tabs in Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I recently installed **Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)** in **Ubuntu 14.04**

**Problem 1:**

Its not working well as it is not displaying **Logcat** Tabs as below:

[image]

It is displaying `Level` tab only nothing else so i can not able to see log. I have tried to dragged it, minimized it, but not succeed.

**Problem 2:**

Sometime Project Structure hiding the folders/files in Project Explorer, It show back on mouse hover.

I don't know what is the problem? Is related to **Ubuntu** or **Eclipse** or anything else?

You help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Eclipse is not supported anymore for Android development since june 15: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html

Comment: If i have old projects on eclipse. I do not want to migrate then?

Comment: Well if you dont want to migrate you'll have to deal with old, unsupported tools I guess. Up to you.